# show/hide a div base on a $scope variable that's an integer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following ng repeat

```
<div class="presentForm" id="presentForm{{$index}}"  ng:repeat="slide in slides" style="display: block;">
                <img id ="presentationSlide" ng-src='{{slide}}' style="height: 300px" width="600px">
                <label id="scriptLabel{{$index}}" for="slideScript{{$index}}" style="left:130px;">Slide {{$index + 1}} Script</label>
                <textarea class="scriptText" name="Text" id="slideScript{{$index}}">'{{slide.script}} </textarea>
            </div>
```

I was just wondering how I could show one `id="presentForm{{$index}}"` if `{{$index}}` equals a variable called $scope.display which is an integer. I was hoping to use ng-show/ng-hide but I just can't wrap my head around using angular expressions with a variable that's not a Boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of ng-show/ng-hide is just an expression that can be evaluated into boolean.

So you can have ng-show="$index == display":

```
<div class="presentForm" ng-show="$index == display" id="presentForm{{$index}}"  ng:repeat="slide in slides" style="display: block;">
            <img id ="presentationSlide" ng-src='{{slide}}' style="height: 300px" width="600px">
            <label id="scriptLabel{{$index}}" for="slideScript{{$index}}" style="left:130px;">Slide {{$index + 1}} Script</label>
            <textarea class="scriptText" name="Text" id="slideScript{{$index}}">'{{slide.script}} </textarea>
```

Comment: your second example should be ng-show="{{$index == display}}" cause using the one 1 { } I get a parse error

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't valid at all, was confused by Angular documentation having an example ng-show="{expression}", never actually tried that.

Putting it into double mustache brackets will not work as it will be immediately printed into html.

Comment: Ya angular docs are pretty bads I've conditioned myself to look mostly for third party answers